# podemos tener ancho de columnas automático en {grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, (auto, auto));}?

Tags: css, grid

mi CSS trabaja bien:

```html
<style>
  .tabmag {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(420px, 1fr));
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  
  .tabmag figure {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: lime;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<main class="tabmag">
  <figure>1</figure>
  <figure>DOS</figure>
  <figure>3</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>SÉIS</figure>
  <figure>SIETE</figure>
  <figure>OCHO</figure>
  <figure>NUEVE</figure>
  <figure>DIÉZ</figure>
  <figure>ONCE</figure>
</main>
```

pero necesito que el ancho de cada columna no sea fijo, sino que sea "elástico", con base en el contenido del TAG "figure".

Puede verse que en ocasiones el contenido es de sólo UN carácter, entonces no puedo utilizar `minmax(10px, 1fr)` porque las demás columnas quedan con ése ancho fijo y hay columnas de varios caracteres; gracias por la ayuda.

quizá utilizando ROWS se pueda, pero no sé cómo combinarlos:

```
grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(420px, 1fr));
grid-template-rows:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(420px, 1fr));
```

he encontrado éste y otros:
https://web.dev/patterns/layout/repeat-auto-minmax/demo.html
pero utilizan anchos fijos y como he mencionado, requiero que el ancho de cada columna (no de cada "caja") corresponda al contenido de la PRIMERA caja de la columna.

¿es posible sin utilizar JavaScript?

Comment: No sé si termino de entender lo que necesitas, pero! intenta agregar a la regla `.tabmag` el estilo `display: inline-block;`, eso haría que todo se achique al mínimo posible.

Comment: gracias, solo requiero que las columnas tengan su ANCHO con base a la PRIMER CAJA de cáda columna, no con base a un valor FIJO